# Python problem creating recursion function

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to create a function that
**The input** of it will be a digit.
And the length of the wanted result

**The output** will be the digit in the length of user input

For example doMul(3,6) will output: 333333.

Now I tried to do this:

```
def doMul(digit, count=1):
    if count == 0:
        return 1
    return digit + digit * (10 ** doMul(digit, count - 1))
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
And I can't figure out why.
Worth mentioning I don't want to use any strings.

Comment: `"3" * 6` will produce `"333333"`, you can apply this.

Comment: You should `return digit + 10 * doMul(digit, count - 1)` for the recursion. Also when `count == 0` you should return `digit`, not `1`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght That uses strings, which the OP says they don't want to do.

Comment: @ekhumoro, that's why it's a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 1):

`y ** x` is actually `y` in power of `x`, not multiplication. You should remove it and return `digit` rather than `1`

```
def doMul(digit, count=1):
    if count == 1:
        return digit
    return digit + 10 * doMul(digit, count - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def doMul(n, m):
    "Return the decimal number that is nnn... m times."

    return n * ((10**m)-1) // 9
```

The reason this works is that M copies of N is simply M copies of 1, multiplied by N. And since (10 ** M) - 1 is the same as `doMul(9, m)`, we can easily generate our base number.

If you absolutely need a recursive solution:

```
def doMul(n, m):
    if m <= 1:
        return n
    return n + 10 * doMul(n, m-1)
```

This does essentially the same, compute one digit less than we want, multiply it by 10, then add the digit we want.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you?

```
def doMul(digit, count=1):
    if count == 1:
        return digit
    return str(digit) + str(doMul(digit, count-1))

print(doMul(3, 6))
```

Comment: From the question: _"Worth mentioning I don't want to use any strings."_